# How to remove the “Have offline access” permission on Android using oAuth

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to remove the “Have offline access” permission on my Android app.

In my application, when I click in sign me with Google it is showing me this:

[image]

I don't want that message

I'm using "GoogleApiClient" like this for the initialization:

```
// Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
```

I search over internet, but I can't found how to do that in Android. I only found information about Web Server Applications and the approval_prompt parameter.

Someone have any idea of how to do that on Android?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

That is the scope of permissions your application is requesting.  Users need to know what permissions you want to access If you want to remove that you will have to remove

```
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
```

But then you will not be able to access the users account either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, why “Have offline access” ? I only want to do oAuth login. Why it is showing me “Have offline access”?

Comment: Because Google said that's what it should say.  Technically speaking you do get offline access.    There is no way to change that text it was chosen by Google.